# How to explain "repository moved" when the link is still the same?

Tags: git

I created a private repository on github and after some pushes where I did not notice anything unusual, I started getting the following message on `git push`:

```
$ git push
Enumerating objects: 20, done.
Counting objects: 100% (20/20), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
Writing objects: 100% (14/14), 46.54 KiB | 117.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 14 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (8/8), completed with 4 local objects.
remote: This repository moved. Please use the new location:
remote:   https://github.com/lucidBrot/cevi-versand.git
To https://github.com/lucidbrot/cevi-versand.git
   d4cfadf..ae2909b  master -> master

$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/lucidbrot/cevi-versand.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/lucidbrot/cevi-versand.git (push)
```

Git claims that the repository moved. But the "new location" it suggests is the same url as the one I am currently using.
This happens on both machines I access this repo from. I haven't yet tried reproducing with an empty repo.

Why am I receiving this message, and how do i get rid of it?

I am using git through cygwin:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.21.0
```

Comment: @Aomine 's edit removed the tag [[github]]. I can see why, but perhaps it actually has to do with github?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the messages, I can see:

From:

> https: //github.com/lucid**B**rot/cevi-versand.git

To:

> https: //github.com/lucid**b**rot/cevi-versand.git

Looks like the server is case-sensitive. Probably not a big deal, but if the software simply sticks to comparing strings, this could explain the issue.

Comment: oh wow, thanks! I did not realize that after proofreading multiple times. Guess I should've used a diff tool for that

Comment: Yeah. `git remote remove origin && git remote add origin https://github.com/lucidBrot/cevi-versand.git && git push -u origin master` did the trick